# What is the equivalent of Ninject.IKernel in Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject-extensions

This may seem odd but what is the equivalent of `Ninject.IKernel` interface in Unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity that would be the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer` interface.

This is the main interface in Unity which collects the methods for registration (`RegisterType`, `RegisterInstance`), resolvig (`Resolve`) , configuration (`AddExtension`) etc. See also on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.iunitycontainer_members(v=pandp.30).aspx)